# Call method from Main Form to another class

Tags: c#, winforms, methods

I know that this have been asked before but i cant find the right post with the solution.

Im working in a winform project and i need to call a method from my main form to another class.

> My code:

```
public void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (checkBox1.Checked)
   {
     Thread.Sleep(2000);         
   }    
}
```

I want to call this method in another class so that only if the checkbox is enabled the sleep will be done.

Sorry for the confusion, if you need something more just ask.

Comment: Have the checkbox set a bool in your [App Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/using-application-settings-and-user-settings). Then have the "another class" check that App Setting. You may also read up on UI best practices in C# .net / WinForms and "MVC", "MVVM" and related patterns.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve this is to make a public static class called Settings and let the checkbox write a value there. This static class can then be read from the another class easily.
Also its easy to add more stuff to this Settings class

```
public static class Settings
{ 
    private static bool _checkChanged;

    public static CheckChanged
    {
         get { return _checkChanged; }
         set { _checkChanged = value; }
    }
}


public void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Settings.CheckChanged = checkBox1.Checked;
}
```

then from the other class do

```
if (Settings.CheckChanged)
{
    // do here whatever it takes...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need to know if the checkbox is checked from another class. There are multiple ways to do it.

1. Pass reference to the checkbox when you're initializing the other class. You create the class with something like `MyClass foo = new MyClass(...);`. Simply pass the checkbox to class constructor: `MyClass foo = new MyClass(checkBox1, ...)`.
2. Expose the checkbox as static. You *shouldn't* do this, as this is bad idea to do and if you need to do it, your application is not designed well. However, if you need it... Add `public static CheckBox checkbox;` to your form, and in constructor of your form add `checkbox = checkBox1;`. Then, you can access the checkbox with `<YourForm>.checkbox`.
3. Use [App Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/using-application-settings-and-user-settings) as Fildor suggested. This is probably the best way, but it might be hard to do if you're unexperienced.

Definitelly find some tutorial or guide on how to design WinForms applications, otherwise you'll run into problems once you start doing something bigger. And if you're new to WinForms, consider using [WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/getting-started/introduction-to-wpf-in-vs), which is basically modern WinForms. WinForms is outdated technology and is no longer developed.

Comment: Idea #1 is just as bad as #2. For one, you'd introduce a dependency. And then you would have to instantiate `MyClass` in a scope where checkBox1 is available. Really bad design choice. The answer is some kind of model. Doesn't have to be the App Settings. You could also use some static class or Singleton or Service ...

Comment: He asked the way, I assume, he's new to this and his design is bad right now, and the best design choice would be to start over. Adding dependency isn't that bad in the context, especially it's probably the easiest way to do it. If he wanted to do it with correct design, he should read some tutorial and start over. I disagree that it's as bad as #2. 

Yes, one could use static class or custom settings, but that's basically the same thing as App Settings as you said before, just custom, and more simple, one.